# how to call multiple function one by one on single button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native. I have a single button. and I have 3 functions. so I want that when user click on first time then first function should be call. when user click on 2nd time then 2nd function should be call. when user click on 3rd time then 3rd function should be call. and when user click on 4th time then again first function should be call and so on. please help me. thanks.

here is my code

```
<View>
<Icon onPress={this.function} name="md-camera" size={30}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to maintain a count that how many times the functions has been triggered. And using that you can choose whether which function to execute when button presses.

Note: I hope that you are using class components because you mentioned onPress event with `this` keyword and also function name is equal to `function`.

### Class components

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        triggerCount: 0
    };

    this.functionName = this.functionName.bind(this);
    this.function1 = this.function1.bind(this);
    this.function2 = this.function2.bind(this);
    this.function3 = this.function3.bind(this);
}

functionName() {
    switch (this.state.triggerCount) {
        case 0:
            this.function1();
            break;
        case 1:
            this.function2();
            break;
        case 2:
            this.function3();
            break;
    }

    this.setState({
        triggerCount: (this.state.triggerCount + 1) % 3
    });
}

function1() {
    // Your logic for function 1
}

function2() {
    // Your logic for function 2
}

function3() {
    // Your logic for function 3
}

render() {
    return (
        ...
        <View>
            <Icon onPress={this.functionName} name="md-camera" size={30}/>
        </View>
        ...
    )
}
```

or

### Functional components

```
const [triggerCount, setTriggerCount] = useState(0);

const functionName = () => {
    switch (triggerCount) {
        case 0:
            function1();
            break;
        case 1:
            function2();
            break;
        case 2:
            function3();
            break;
    }

    setTriggerCount((triggerCount + 1) % 3);
}

const function1 = () => {
    // Your logic for function 1
}

const function2 = () => {
    // Your logic for function 2
}

const function3 = () => {
    // Your logic for function 3
}

return (
    ...
    <View>
        <Icon onPress={functionName} name="md-camera" size={30}/>
    </View>
    ...
);
```

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.triggerCount')

Comment: Have you bound `this` to functions in the constructor. No worries, I've updated the answer according your error and added how to bind a function to `this`. You can now continue.

Comment: thanku but i got my answer and you code also working thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need 4 functions for this and one counter. Forth function will choose your function .

```
   state = {
    count: 0
  };



_gateway=()=>{
   this.setState({
            count: this.state.count==3 ? 1 : this.state.count+1
        })
   if(this.state.count==1){
      _function1();
   }
   if(this.state.count==2){
      _function2();
   }
   if(this.state.count==3){
      _function3();
   }
}
_function1=()=>{

    }
_function2=()=>{

    }
_function3=()=>{

    }
```

and in button call the _gateway function on press

```
onPress{() => { this._gateway();}}
```

Comment: its automatically launching camera